# How to use web services in flutter?

Tags: android, web-services, flutter, dart

Is possible to make `Post` request in flutter using web service made with java 
And how can i access to all methods in this web service ?

Comment: is this web service RESTful? SOAP?

Comment: Use the [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package

Comment: its SOAP made with java